# mac use node from .nvm and not /usr/local/bin/node

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm trying to use specific LTE version of node and therefore installed nvm to manage it, however when I type which node I see that mac os is using the system version located in:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

instead of the defined default version from nvm located in:

```
~/.nvm
```

Do I need to delete /usr/local/bin/node?

Comment: I'd recommend you put in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` this : `PATH=~/.nvm/bin:$PATH`

Comment: As @Philippe says, your shell looks up programs to run using `PATH` so either change your PATH, or explicitly use an absolute command every time, e.g `~/.nvm/bin/node`